# How can I launch gitahed from terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, gitahead

I enjoy using gitahed, and I would like to add a shortcut to lauch it, with github desktop I use github-desktop, but I can do the same with GA?
How can I launch gitahed from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitAhead has a Terminal panel at Tools->Options. It has a button to install command line tools. It really just creates a symlink to the GitAhead binary in /usr/local/bin. If that doesn't work for some reason, you can create the symlink yourself or an alias. See command line options by running with the `--help` flag. There are only a few at the moment.